# How to configure checkstyle for new android unit test structure

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, checkstyle

I have been referring this [android testing template](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint) project from google samples for unit testing, How do I set up checkstyle rule with the new unit test directory structure.

I'm using the following gradle checkstyle script

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "6.7"
    configFile rootProject.file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
    showViolations true
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.name

    def checkstyle = project.tasks.create "checkstyle${name.capitalize()}", Checkstyle
    checkstyle.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    checkstyle.source variant.javaCompile.source
    checkstyle.classpath = project.fileTree(variant.javaCompile.destinationDir)
    checkstyle.exclude('**/Manifest.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/BuildConfig.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/R.java')
    project.tasks.getByName("check").dependsOn checkstyle
}
```

And this is my hack to include unit test directories, And of course the `src` should be dynamically picked by the flavor naming standards. Any suggestion on how to get the variant src directory path?

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.name
    def checkstyle = project.tasks.create "checkstyle${name.capitalize()}", Checkstyle
    checkstyle.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    checkstyle.source variant.javaCompile.source
    checkstyle.source project.files("src/test${name.capitalize()}")
    checkstyle.classpath = project.fileTree(variant.javaCompile.destinationDir) + project
            .fileTree(dir: "src/test${name.capitalize()}")
    checkstyle.exclude('**/Manifest.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/BuildConfig.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/R.java')
    project.tasks.getByName("check").dependsOn checkstyle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `checkstyle.source 'src'`. This works for me.

Comment: you mean by not looping thru android variants? let me try that

Comment: my project has flavors, had to loop variants to get the src files of each flavors, Also I cannot hardcode the directory files because I'm sharing this gradle script file in multiple projects

Comment: I have been going thru android gradle plugin docs about TestVariant which we can get from each variant, is there anyway to get the source files from them, I tried `variant.testVariant.javaCompile` it returns null

Comment: looks like I had to write 2 checkstyle task, also the testVariant only includes `androidTest` folders

Comment: take a look at http://vincentbrison.com/2014/07/19/how-to-improve-quality-and-syntax-of-your-android-code/

Comment: You don't have to write that checkstyle configuration again and again for each module, you can re-use them

Comment: yes im following the same pattern, but i had to loop thru variants for flavor source files, your config runs it only for src directory, in my project some flavors has java files in srcFlavorName/main/java

Comment: Im adding one more task loop all test directories